# Email Not Sent, Error 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Clear Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgcJ0.png)
Here is the code that sends the email, I really dont know why it doesnt send when I'm using it as a mobile app

```
    receiverEmail = inputEmail.text;

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress(senderEmail);
    mail.To.Add(receiverEmail);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(server);
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword) as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors){
        return true;
    };


    try
    {
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
        emailStatus.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Email Sent !!";
    }

    catch (SmtpException error)
    {
        Debug.Log (error.StatusCode);
        Debug.Log (error.Message);

        emailStatus.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Email Not Sent \n" +error.Message+ "\n Error Number : "+ error.StatusCode;
    }
```

Comment: I dont see you turn of UseDefaultCredentials ?

Comment: I already did "smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;" and the error still occurs

Comment: what .net are you compiling up with? which version of unity?

Comment: Does 2.0 and 2.0 subset differ from each other?

Comment: about as much as Canda is not the US..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bugfinder, it really was the .net, I changed mine to 2.0 from 2.0 subset and its working fine